# Add hover on css class

Tags: css

I use bootstrap and datatable.

I created this class.

```
.nonCompliant{
    background: #de5d5d;
}
```

It put on the tr of some row of the table.

Would like to put another color when nonCompliant class is displayed and hover event

tried

```
table#samplesTestsTable.dataTable tbody tr:hover > .nonCompliant{
    background: #c11f1f;
}
```

and

```
tr:hover > .nonCompliant{
    background: #c11f1f;
}
```

without good result.

Edit code of the row

```
<tr role="row" class="nonCompliant even"><td data-id="19475A" class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">190475A</td><td>2019-04-23</td></tr>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML with CSS?

Comment: Try `tr.nonCompliant:hover` if the class is applied on the `tr`

Comment: Your code selects a `<tr>` element's *direct child* that has the class "nonCompliant". It seems you want to select a `<tr>` that has that class itself. See [Combinators and selector lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Combinators_and_selector_lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the .nonCompliant class is modifying the tr itself, then

```
.nonCompliant:hover {
   background: #c11f1f;
}
```

should work. Otherwise if .nonCompliant is on a direct child element of the tr, like a td,

```
tr:hover .nonCompliant {
   background: #c11f1f;
}
```

or the child selector you're already using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying the class directly to the `hr` tag, then you can just do this:

```css
.someclass:hover{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="someclass">
    Hello2
</td>
    <td>Lastname</th>
    <td>Age</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

else, if its a direct child you could to this:

```
tr:hover .nonCompliant {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```